# Scrapy nested page crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

I am struggling with nested page crawling.

I only get the items as number as the first crawled page item count.

The site structure will be like this.

1. Crawl Brands - Brand links
2. Using Brand links go and crawl Models and Model links
3. Using Model links go and crawl a specific announcement and its attributes.

Lets say Brand A has 2 Models and in first model there are 11 announcements, in second model there are 9. Brand B has 3 Models and each model has 5 announcements.

In the example above I need to get each announcement as separate item (total 35), but instead of that I get items number as Brands like Brand A with first announcement, then Brand B with first announcement.

```
class SiteSpider(CrawlSpider):
log.start(logfile="log.txt", loglevel="DEBUG", logstdout=None)
name = "site"
#download_delay = 2
allowed_domains = ['site.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.site.com/search.php?c=1111']
items = {}


def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    #requests =[]
    brands = sel.xpath("//li[@class='class_11']")
    for brand in brands:
        item = SiteItem()
        url = brand.xpath('a/@href')[0].extract()
        item['marka'] = brand.xpath("a/text()")[0].extract()
        item['marka_link'] =  brand.xpath('a/@href')[0].extract()
        request = Request("http://www.site.com"+url,callback=self.parse_model, meta={'item':item})
        # requests.append(request)
        #
        yield request

def parse_model(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    models = sel.xpath("//li[@class='class_12']")
    for model in models:

        item = SiteUtem(response.meta["item"])
        url2 = model.xpath('a/@href')[0].extract()
        item ['model'] = model.xpath("a/text()")[0].extract()
        item ['model_link'] = url2

    return item
```

Could you please help this noobie with pseudo code to implement this? I am making a mistake at foundation level I guess.

Comment: Hi Paul, 

Thanks for the interest. I added the code so far I tried to implement.

I am doing it step by step approach since I am new to python and scrapy. 

In first parsing function I tried to get brand and brand's link. I am able to do this and get whole list of brands. But the trick is it creates number of items as number of brands.

It looks like an issue with the algorithm which I am trying to implement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your `parse_model` you have a loop that create items but not yielding them, try to change it to:

```
def parse_model(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    models = sel.xpath("//li[@class='class_12']")
    for model in models:

        item = SiteUtem(response.meta["item"])
        url2 = model.xpath('a/@href')[0].extract()
        item ['model'] = model.xpath("a/text()")[0].extract()
        item ['model_link'] = url2

        yield item
```